# generating a row depending on 5 distinct tables rails 3.0.1 ruby 1.8.7

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

i have to generate a report that needs to compare data from 5 tables (User,Order,Product,Rating,OrderProduct) like this:

User has many Orders (user_id in Order)
Product has many children of itself through the field father_id
User and Products has many Ratings (user_id and product_id in Rating)
Order and Product has many of each other through OrderProducts(order_id and   product_id in OrderProduct)

i need to bring all the registers in Products, per User where Products and User are not in Rating

in other words: bring all the users that buyed and not rated a product and the products the buyer didn't rate

on top of that, i need to bring the father of those Products when the father_id is not null.

EDIT1: so, i edited the models' names, and i managed to think a little clearer: I need to bring the Products that were not Rated in an Order and show the Buyer(User related to the order in question)

I can't think clearer than that right now, sry about it.

EDIT2: https://gist.github.com/rmatuoka/c73e41a2aa475d3b5a29

if you downvote, at least tell me why :)

thanks for the attention.

Comment: So you want `father_id, product_id, user_id` where the user has made an order for the product, but has not left a rating?

Comment: i think that it describes well what i'm asking. thx for simplifying it. one detail, there is many `product_id` for each `user_id`. And when the `father_id` is not null, the product is a flavor and i need to call it's father.

Comment: my gist returns a string array, not an object, so a can't acess the `father_id` that i get to call the father element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be pretty close... please check all table and field names carefully as I needed to guess at some of them (for instance, I'm assuming that the `products` table has an attribute `parent_id` which links to the next product level).  For this to run at scale, you will definitely need to have the right indexes in place and may even need to tune your design a bit.

```
@users_not_rated = User.find_by_sql("
  SELECT pp.product_id AS father_id, p.product_id, u.user_id FROM products p
  INNER JOIN products pp ON p.parent_id = pp.product_id
  INNER JOIN order_products op ON p.product_id = op.product_id
  INNER JOIN orders o ON op.order_id = o.order_id
  INNER JOIN users u ON o.user_id = u.user_id
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT r.user_id, r.product_id FROM ratings r
    WHERE r.user_id = u.user_id
    AND r.product_id = p.product_id
  )
")
```

Basically, join everything together and then only return rows without a rating for that user and product.

Comment: you deserve to go to Valhalla when you die, your query saved me a lot of time. sry for not checking earlier, i was busy with other modules of this project.